# USB Wifi adopter Comfast CF-WU715

Tags: raspbian, usb, wifi

I would like to buy **comfast CF-WU715** wifi adopter,In the description of this product they have mentioned that this is supported  Win and linux. So can i use this with raspberry pi b+? [description here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R7GSM9Q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the list of of [RPi verified peripherals](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#), specifically the [USB Wi-Fi adapter section](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters). Consulting the list it does not appear that this adapter is listed as working. This does not mean that it won't work (since it is not included on the problem section of the same list), but if you are new to Linux and the Pi I would not suggest it. You might be better of choosing one of the verified working adapters - even if it costs a little more.

**Edit:**
after doing a little Googling, I came across an [Amazon UK page](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linux-driver-compatible/forum/Fx2QEEXX9U95DLN/Tx2C0ATXAHBQTBV/1/ref=cm_cd_dp_aar_al_a?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00C3F5C1C). Where someone asked this exact question, and received a "Yes it works with the Pi" from two different users. If you do buy this adapter and verify that it works, I suggest you add it to the verified peripheral list as working.

Comment: If i connect raspberry pi using lan to a wifi modem and if i connect to the same wifi network using my laptop can i use ssh to access the Pi?

Comment: @DushyanthShenoy please don't ask a series of questions in the comments or answer section. Please open a new question instead. The answer to your question is if they are both on the same network you should be able to SSH between them.

Comment: Some distributors report it as having an RT5370 chipset, which is apparently supported by the rt2x00 driver, so that should work.  However, beware that Comcast evidently switches chipsets on occasion without changing the model number >_< http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26237/5538